# Python - convert to string with formatter as parameter

Tags: python, format

I am trying to write a function which takes two arguments:

- an object
- a formatter string (as specified in docs)

which then returns a formatted string:
What I tried is sort of:

```
def my_formatter(x, form):
    return str(x).format(form)
```

What I am expecting is:

```
s = my_formatter(5, "%2f")
# s = 05
t = my_formatter(5, "%.2")
# t = 5.00
```

etc...

The format function unfortunately does not work like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that style of formatting you'd have to use the `string % values` [string formatting operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
def my_formatter(x, form):
    return form % x
```

You'd also have to alter your format; to get `05` you'd have to use `"%02d"`, not `"%2f"`.

You were getting confused by the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which uses a different formatting syntax, *and* you got the arguments swapped; you'd use `form.format(x)` instead.

You probably want to look into the built-in [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) here; the syntax is slightly different, but offers more features:

```
>>> format(5, '02d')
'05'
>>> format(5, '.2f')
'5.00'
```

That's pretty close to what you were already using, minus the `%`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly, I was confused by the `str.format` method